# Why does DHCP keep getting turned off (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, dhcp, docker-for-windows

Every time I reboot my Windows 10 PC, DHCP gets disabled for my WIFI connection. I have to go into the adapter settings, TCP/IP v4, and turn it back on. Initially the settings look like this:

[image]

I believe this started happening right after I installed [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Comment: Possibly this....https://arstechnica.com/business/2016/12/microsoft-windows-10-dhcp-broken-update/

Comment: Use this command as admin:: `netsh interface ip set address "interface name" dhcp`